# Is Eve or Margo Nick Marshall's mother?

Tags: character, what-women-want

In [*What Women Want*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0207201/fullcredits/), we are informed in the beginning of the movie that when Nick was a child, Nick's mother (who was a Vegas showgirl) and all of her showgirl friends absolutely adored him and how he had all of them wrapped around his finger.

When we see Nick at present day, there are two older women who are constantly fawning all over him and complimenting him every time we see them.  Nick only refers to them as "girls" or "ladies"

[image: Valerie and Margo]

They are listed in the credits as Eve and Margo.  I don't recall Nick or anyone else ever refer to them by first name.  I certainly don't recall Nick referring to any of them as "mother."

**Are one of these women Nick's mother**?

Answer (score 5):

[Mel Gibson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000154/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t1) (who plays Nick Marshall) was born in 1956, making him 44 years old at the time this movie was released.

[Delta Burke](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004785/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t8) (Eve) was also born in 1956, roughly 6 months after Mr. Gibson.

[Valerie Perrine](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0674781/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t9) (Margo) was born in 1943, making her 57 years old at the time the movie was released.

I don't recall anything in the movie to suggest any of these characters are significantly older or younger than the actors who portray them, which would suggest to me that **no, neither of these women is intended to be Nick's mother.**  Margo would've had to give birth at the tender age of 13 for that to work out (which adds a whole new layer of cringe onto an already cringeworthy film.)

Also, movies are not generally shy about announcing who's related to whom (unless it's [a major plot twist](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/luke-i-am-your-father),) so if either of these characters were intended to be his mother, I would have expected him to call her "mom" at some point.

Comment: You think that this is a cringeworthy film?  I always found this film to be hilarious!  It's one of those films that I always have to watch whenever it's on.  That aside, good answer.  I always wondered who those two women were.  I always assumed that one of them were his mother since they are always fawning all over him and they never have any negative "thoughts" about him when he can hear what women are thinking.

Comment: Why do the actors' ages matter in this (or any movie) when discussing characters?

Comment: Barring evidence to the contrary I tend to assume as much about an actor as possible carries over into the character.  ie: unless the character's age is stated explicitly (or there's an in-universe reason to believe it's different) it just makes sense to say they're the same age as the actor.  I mean, if there isn't any such reason, then why would you think they *aren't* the same age?

Comment: @Steve-O because actors are not hired because they are the age of the character they portray, but because they can portray the character. And because you can't pinpoint a person's age based on appearance or behaviour anyway. There are many, many, many examples of a discrepancy between an actors age and the age of the character (even where a specific age is not mentioned - but 20 something's playing high school students is a great example), so much so that it just doesn't make sense to assume anything about a character's age based on the actor's.

Comment: @HorusKol The high school thing is an excellent example of exactly what I meant by *"in-universe reason to believe" their ages are different.*  **Lacking any such reason** I'm inclined to assume the character is the same age as the actor, and that - *in combination with the fact that Nick doesn't explicitly identify either character as his mother* - leaves me inclined to believe neither of them is.  No one said you have to agree with my answer, but this makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @Steve-O and I'm inclined to believe that lead actors typical play a character 5-10 years younger than their true age. All bets are off on extras, however. And I don't disagree with your answer, I disagree with your reasoning

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside what we know about the ages of the players (I'm sorry - that information is inadmissible for the purposes of determining character age and relationship), you shouldn't have to look any further than the fact that he refers to them as 'girls' and or 'ladies'.  No man would talk to his mother like that, even one as base as this character.